# Makefile: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm making my app more portable to run on other OS's. Works in XCode and Visual Studio. However, switching to Makefiles is causing me some problems.

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:                                     
"AppObject::Instance()", referenced from:                        
  _main in main-329f6c.o                                                                                          
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "AppObject.hpp"

AppObject* _appObject;

int main()
{
    _appObject = AppObject::Instance();

    return 0;
}
```

AppObject.hpp

```
#ifndef  _APPOBJECT_HPP_
#define  _APPOBJECT_HPP_

#include <iostream>

class AppObject
{
    public:
        static AppObject* Instance();
        virtual ~AppObject() {}

        void initInstance();

    private:
        AppObject();
        AppObject(const AppObject&);
        AppObject& operator= (const AppObject&);
        static AppObject* pinstance; 
};

#endif // _APPOBJECT_HPP_
```

AppObject.cpp

```
#include "AppObject.hpp"

AppObject* AppObject::pinstance = 0;

AppObject::AppObject() {}

AppObject* AppObject::Instance()
{
    if (pinstance == 0)
    {
        pinstance = new AppObject;
        pinstance->initInstance();
    }

    return pinstance;
}

void AppObject::initInstance()
{
   .....
}
```

This is paired down a bit but I am seeing some other warnings also of:

```
warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension
```

Can anyone help me understand my mistake and my this works in XCode and VS but not using make?

Makefile

```
CXX=clang++
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -c

LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include

SOURCES=scraper/main.cpp scraper/AppObject.cpp scraper/SQLManager.cpp

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

EXECUTABLE=scraper

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Full make output:

```
$ make
clang  scraper/main.cpp -o scraper/main.o
In file included from scraper/main.cpp:3:
In file included from scraper/AppObject.hpp:6:
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:44:30: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension
  [-Wc++11-extensions]
        bool _bDatabaseReady = false;
                         ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:46:29: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension
  [-Wc++11-extensions]
        std::string _dbFile = "popcorn.db3";
                        ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:47:29: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension
  [-Wc++11-extensions]
        std::string _dbName = "popcorn";
                        ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:49:24: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
        int _dbVersion = 1; // increment this when database structure changes
                   ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:51:28: warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
        int _dbVersionType = 0; // 0 = normal, 1 = free, 2 = lite
                       ^
5 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "AppObject::Instance()", referenced from:
      _main in main-4a5276.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
make: *** [scraper/main.o] Error 1
```

Updated `make` output after taking advice from replies:

```
$ make
clang++  scraper/main.cpp -o scraper/main.o
In file included from scraper/main.cpp:3:
In file included from scraper/AppObject.hpp:6:
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:44:30: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        bool _bDatabaseReady = false;
                         ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:46:29: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        std::string _dbFile = "popcorn.db3";
                        ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:47:29: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        std::string _dbName = "popcorn";
                        ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:49:24: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        int _dbVersion = 1; // increment this when database structure changes
                   ^
scraper/SQLManager.hpp:51:28: warning: in-class initialization of non-    static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        int _dbVersionType = 0; // 0 = normal, 1 = free, 2 = lite
                       ^
5 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "AppObject::Instance()", referenced from:
      _main in main-0e97bb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
make: *** [scraper/main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You build your C++ sources with C flags.

Comment: And totally unrelated to your problem, but still relevant: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: And please copy-paste the full output of your run with `make`. Delete all object, executable and other temporary files, and run a clean `make`.

Comment: Use `$(CXX)` to build and link C++ sources, `$(CC)` is for C.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I switched to `$(CXX)` and the errors persist.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the links, I'll read.

Comment: @Jason It will be a lot easier to see where the error is if you show us all the commands being run (that is, delete all object and exe files, run make and copy paste the output)

Comment: @nos post updated with full output. Some classes referenced I omitted from this post.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, `clang` is the ***C*** frontend. While it can be used to compile C++ code, it will not add all header paths or linker libraries needed for C++. Use `clang++`.

Secondly, the output you show is without any flags at all.

Thirdly, and the reason for your linker error, is that you don't use the `-c` flag which is needed to create object files. Without the `-c` flag, you tell the `clang` frontend program to build and link an **executable** file named `scraper/main.o`.

Comment: I fixed those and still the same errors. I updated the Makefile above to reflect

Comment: @Jason But you forgot to update the output you get from building. And if you get the exact same output, then you're not editing with the `Makefile` you're using to build.

Comment: hmm, I am editing the makefile I am using (doing so from a command-line). I am getting the same output, but I'll update to show it is now using `clang++` and `-c`.